# Cannot bind bit-field to non-const reference of type unsigned int

Tags: c++

I am trying to cast 8 bit unsigned integers in C++ but I am getting an error. I am sorry I am not being specific enough this is my first time asking for help. I am writing in C++. Anything is appreciated my code is below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct address{ //page 3 on assignment doc
    unsigned int num1 : 8; // 8 bit unsigned int values
    unsigned int num2 : 8;
    unsigned int num3 : 8;
    unsigned int num4 : 8;
};
    
//unsigned int num1; 
//unsigned int num2;
//unsigned int num3;
//unsigned int num4;

int main ()
{
    address ip;

    std::cout << "Enter four 8-bit unsigned integer values" << std::endl;

    //int temp1;
    //int temp2;
    //int temp3;
    //int temp4;

    std::cin >> ip.num1 >> ip.num2 >> ip.num3 >> ip.num4;
    // ip.num1 = temp1;
    // ip.num2 = temp2;
    //ip.num3 = temp3;
    //ip.num4 = temp4;

    std::cout <<    "How would you like to see your IP address? (1) Single value, (2) Four values, (3)          

     Two values, (4) A Signle bit value "   << std::endl;

    int oneToFour;
    std::cin >> oneToFour;

    switch (oneToFour) // page 43 for switch statement
    {                           
    case 1:
        break;
    case 2:
        std::cout <<  ip.num1 << '.' << ip.num2 << '.' << ip.num3 << '.' << ip.num4 << std::endl;
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[ERROR]

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:43:19: error: cannot bind bit-field ‘ip.address::num2’ to ‘unsigned int&’
   43 |   std::cin  >> ip.num2 >> ip.num3 >> ip.num4;
      |                ~~~^~~~
```

At first it was all 4 numbers that could not be casted, I then changed the `CIN` statement and now it's whatever is first in the `CIN` does not work.

Comment: FWIW, searching for the error text turned up that duplicate really quickly. That's always a good first step if you don't understand it.

Comment: Terminology note: You don't really have `cin` statements. In `std::cin >> ip.num1 >> ip.num2 >> ip.num3 >> ip.num4;`, `std::cin` is just an argument to `operator>>`  just like `ip.num1` is. `operator>>` usually looks something like `std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & stream_to_write_to, TYPE & value_to_write)`. The return type of `std::istream &` returns the stream argument allowing the operations to be chained: `std::cin  >> ip.num2` returns `std::cin` to be used as the left hand for the `>> ip.num3` that follows.

Answer (score 2):

```
unsigned int num1 : 8;
```

This is not an 8-bit unsigned integer value. It's a [bitfield](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field). Those come with all *kinds* of messy corner cases, one of which being that you can't take references to it. The use cases for bitfields are pretty minimal, so they're generally best avoided unless you know *exactly* what you're doing.

You almost certainly want an *actual* unsigned integer. For most general-purposes use cases, just use `int` and let the compiler deal with it. If you actually need to specify the size, use [fixed width integer types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) such as `uint8_t`.

Comment: Thank you for your message, I tried this uint8_t, now it only receives 2 inputs before the programs closes itself

Comment: I believe I figured it out so far, CIN statements are limited so I had to put them into temp int values and then cast them to the bit fields. I think

Comment: `uint8_t` is typically a synonym for `unsigned char`. All the `char` variants are treated specifically on input and output because they’re used to hold character codes. `int x; std::cin >> x;` will insist on only digits in the input. `char ch; std::cin >> ch;` will be happy with any single character.